# About the Vilsmeier-Haack formylation of this compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, electrophilic-substitution

I was reading an article and found the following reaction sequence:
[image]

The second step involves a formylation of the hydrazone with the Vilsmeier reagent to, first synthesize the pyrazole ring and then, to formylate it to produce the final compound. However, when reviewing this reaction I found many examples in which it is used to formylate phenols and other electron-rich arenes. My question is why doesn't the formylation occur on the phenol of the example?

I'd appreciate if someone could provide an answer.

Comment: The hydrazone exists as an imine/enamine tautomeric equilibrium and attacks the Vilsmeier reagent when in enamine form. Could it be that the enamine is so electron-rich that it attacks the Vilsmeier reagent faster than the phenol ring could? Maybe the phenol ring acts as an electron-donating group to the enamine and this promotes the attack? Is the pyrazole ring much more reactive than the phenol so that it gets formylated before the phenol?